# Creating a form thats gives user chance to filter nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Im quet new to Drupal and i dont know how to search for the module i need.

So the idea is...
I made a content type with the following fields: Name, Description, Country, Category. 
The Country field is a list item and the Category is a checkbox item.

So the idea is that the users can submit they nodes. I undestand that part.

The problem is i want to display the nodes based on the Category and Country items.

When the user comes to the home page, they should first see a form in witch they chose the Category and Country, so the nodes get displayed based on that pick.

It should be a filter sistem where they can pick one country, and multiple categorys to display the Name and Description fields.

Can anyone give me a idea how to make that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Views:

- create a new view, page or block limited to that content type, as the display format you want (table, teaser, etc)
- create a filter field, choose the Country
- click on 'Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it'
- Filter: operator - is equal to (you can expose this operator if desired, allowing the user to choose is equal to, is not equal to, contains, etc)
- if you want the View empty to start, click on 'required' in the filter field set up
- create a new filter field for Category and repeat the same steps

You will want to play around with the settings to get it exactly how you want, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: you deleted the comment about it disappearing with Category while I was writing a response - I assume you got it to work?

Comment: Yes, ill write it in case somebody els gets the same problem. So if there is no node for the default selected filter value, the whole filter wont show on the site. So just add a node and it will show again.